# Vagrant Inline run triggers don't recognize IO redirection

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I don't know why, but Vagrant doesn't seem to create a public key from its auto-generated private key. So I've tried to create it after the `up` command:

```rb
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", 1]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 512]
  end

  config.trigger.after :up do |trigger|
    vagrant_priv_key = ".vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key"
    trigger.run = {
      inline: "ssh-keygen -y -f #{vagrant_priv_key} > #{vagrant_priv_key}.pub"
    }
  end
end
```

Running the `Vagrantfile` above fails:

```
  ...
  default: Too many arguments.
==> default: Trigger run failed
==> default: A script exited with an unacceptable exit code 1.
```

After some investigation, I've figured out that I/O redirection doesn't work with the `inline` shell setting, using the `path` shell setting works but I don't want to create a file for this simple command.

Comment: Did you tried to do it on provision? EX: `config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $script`

Comment: Vagrant runs provisions on the guest machine. I will temporarily use the `path` shell setting and file a bug report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Turns out](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/10674#issuecomment-466132557) the `run` option executes a shell subprocess, I should run the script in a bash session:

```rb
config.trigger.after :up do |trigger|
    vagrant_priv_key = ".vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key"
    trigger.run = {
      inline: "/bin/bash -c 'ssh-keygen -y -f #{vagrant_priv_key} > #{vagrant_priv_key}.pub'"
    }
end
```